# Dictionary of unique values and their occurances - Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm told to

> Write a method freq(a) that returns a dictionary that, for each unique
>   value x in a, maps x onto the number of occurrences of x in a.

This is my first time working with dictionaries and I tried reading up to see how I would attack this problem, but I'm not sure how to code it..

This is what I believe I have to do..
1. create a dictionary with two values. [x:y]
2. evaluate the list.
3.1 if the value in the list is not in the dictionary, make the value x:1
3.2 if the value in the list is in the dictionary, make the value y+1
4. return results

is this how you would do this problem?
how would I code step 3?

Comment: In real life, you'd use a `collections.Counter`...too bad this is homework...

Comment: Its shockingly easy to create the dictionary manually as well -- `for i in L: if D.has(i): D[i]++`; etc.

Comment: Except that that's nowhere near valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without using either `collections.Counter` or `collections.defaultdict`:

```
def freq(a):
    D = {}
    for v in a:
        D[v] = D.get(v, 0) + 1
    return D
```

Comment: Thank you, gotta read on .get, have not seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it. To check if a value is in the dictionary, just use `in`:

```
d = {1:2, 3:4}

print 1 in d # ==> True
print 2 in d # ==> False
```

Then all you have to do is set the values appropriately using `d[x] = y`.